# photoelectric cell

Tags: thermal-radiation

In the photoelectric cell my teacher says that the electron emission from the cathode depends on the frequency of the incident photon and it doesn't depend on the light intensity (I = nhU/ta , Right?) so if the  light intensity increased the photoelectric current won't change .

but what if this increase in the light intensity is due to an increase in the frequency(energy) of each photon.

to make a correct statement shouldn't the light intensity be replaced with rate of photons?

so that if the number of photons increased even to millions and if the frequency of each
was less than the threshold frequency , the photoelectric current won't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not what your teacher said (or if he did, he should be fired). What he most likely said was that electron emission will not take place at all for photons of wavelengths longer than the critical value.  Certainly for shorter wavelength, i.e. higher energy photons, the number of electrons generated is proportional to the number of photons incident.